# ReactJS dynamically add key to array of mixed content

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a `bootstrap` v3, `ReactJS` component using `TypeScript`.

The props are as following:

```
export interface ICheckboxProps {
    checked?: boolean;
    text: string | JSX.Element | (string | JSX.Element)[];
    onChange?: (checked: boolean) => void;
}
```

As it can be seen, `text` can be a `string`, an `JSX.Element` or a listing of both.

This is the `render` method:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    const { text, checked = false } = this.props;

    if (text instanceof Array) {
        // what should I do with?
    }

    return (
        <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={checked} />{text}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In another component I use this one `<Checkbox text={["I accept the ", <Oem.ExternalLink href={"https://some.link.here"} linkText={"terms & conditions"} />]} />`

However, I get the following error/warning:

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Checkbox`

I know that it is related to the `text` property but I have no idea how I should add a key (even if I know that text is an array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate through the array and apply the `key` prop to any JSX element you find. You can do this with `React.cloneElement()`.

```
if (text instanceof Array) {
  text = text.map((item, idx) => {
    if(typeof item === 'string') {
      // if it's a string, then just return it.
      return item;
    }
    // otherwise it's a ReactElement. Return a clone of it with the a key prop.
    return React.cloneElement(text[idx], {key: idx}) )
  });
}
```

More info about [React.cloneElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) on the official docs:

> Clone and return a new React element using `element` as the starting point. The resulting element will have the original element’s props with the new props merged in shallowly. New children will replace existing children. `key` and `ref` from the original element will be preserved.

---

#### Demo

```js
const A = () => <p>bar</p>;
const B = () => <p>bat</p>;

let text = ["foo", <A />, "baz", <B />];

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    if (text instanceof Array) {
      text = text.map((item, idx) => {
        if(typeof item === 'string') {
          return item;
        }
        return React.cloneElement(text[idx], {key: idx})
      });
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I had to change the inner `if` to `typeof item === "string"` as `item instanceof String` seems not to work. But at the end, this worked. Thanks.

Comment: @KingKerosin, yes sorry for that. I added a demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better declare `text` as a single JSX element then wrap it in a `<div>` if you need a text + JSX :

```
<Checkbox text={<div> "I accept the " 
  <Oem.ExternalLink href={"https://some.link.here"} linkText={"terms & conditions"} />
  </div>}
/>
```

Edit : An even better approach is to use the recommanded way using a JSX child :

```
<Checkbox>
  <div>
    "I accept the "
    <Oem.ExternalLink 
       href={"https://some.link.here"}
       linkText={"terms & conditions"} 
    />
  </div>
</Checkbox>
```

Then in Checkbox component :

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    const { children, checked = false } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={checked} />
                {children}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}
```